# Using an international keyboard in iPhone app

Tags: ios, internationalization, keyboard

I need to be able to force a different international keyboard, without the user manually having to go into the Settings application and enable that keyboard.

For example, the user only has English (AU) enabled, and I want to be able to bring up a keyboard for inputting Chinese without them having to enable the keyboard, and switch to that manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[UIKeyboardImpl sharedInstance] setInputMode:@"emoji"];
```

Which, of course, this is undocumented.

Or change `~/Library/Prefereces/.GlobalPreferences.plist` and `~/Library/Prefereces/com.apple.preferences.plist` (the method many apps used to enable Emoji).

---

There's no documented way to force enable a keyboard. Better tell the users to enable it themselves.

Comment: If it's undocumented - would this fail app validation? Doesn't look like "dangerous" code however.

Comment: Is it possible to change the contents of .GlobalPreferences.plist in iOS5, I can read its contents fine, but can't seem to be able to store the updated dictionary? (I have no issues with updating com.apple.preferences.plist entries)